# AES/CBC/PKCS5 Padding | Alternate to mcrypt_get_block_size() in Php OpenSSL

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, aes, mcrypt

### Problem Statement:

I'm trying to integrate API which **AES/CBC/PKCS5** Padding. After some research I found the implementation on [following](https://programmer.help/blogs/php-implementation-of-aes-cbc-pkcs5-padding.html) article.

However, In this article there were using [`mcrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) which is deprecated and removed from PHP 7.2. Hence, I'm looking to modify above implementation in [`openssl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php).

There is function `pkcs5_pad` for **PKCS5** padding the data which require parameter as data and blocksize. And there are no alternative to [`mcrypt_get_block_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-block-size.php) in openssl.

---

### Code Snippet

`pkcs5_pad` & `pkcs5_unpad`

```
function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}


function pkcs5_unpad($text)
{
    $pad = ord($text{strlen($text)-1});
    if ($pad > strlen($text)) return false;
    if (strspn($text, chr($pad), strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad) return false;
    return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
}
```

---

#### Trying to convert following

```
$paddedData = pkcs5_pad(
                            $data, 
                            mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)
                        );


$encrypteddata = mcrypt_encrypt(
                                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                                    hex2bin(md5($key)),
                                    $paddedData,
                                    MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                                    $iv
                                );
```

#### TO

```
$paddedData = pkcs5_pad($data);  // How do I getBlock size in OpenSSL. i.e. Alternate to mcrypt_get_block_size

$encrypteddata = openssl_encrypt(
                                    $paddedData, 
                                    $cipher, 
                                    $key, 
                                    $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, 
                                    $iv
                                );
```

---

#### Trial & Error:

I found some [file](https://github.com/anandsiddharth/laravel-paytm-wallet/issues/8#issuecomment-348568257) after some research in Github. But didn't know how to use this file to convert data into `pkcs5` padded data.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is - OpenSSL has a "built in" padding so you don't have to worry about it.

The full running code below shows you how to encrypt or decrypt a string using a 32 bytes long, randomly generated key for AES-256. The AES mode is **CBC**, and it is using the **PKCS5/7 padding**. The output of the encryption is Base64 encoded (usefull for transport via Email), of course you can leave the Base64 en-/decoding out when saving the ciphertext to a file and later read the file for decryption.

Please be aware that there are is no exception handling and the code is for educational purpose:

```
<?php
function generateRandomAesKey()
{
    return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32, $crypto_strong);
}

function generateRandomInitvector()
{
    return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16, $crypto_strong);
}

function base64Encoding($input)
{
    return base64_encode($input);
}

function base64Decoding($input)
{
    return base64_decode($input);
}

function aesCbcEncryptToBase64($key, $data)
{
    $iv = generateRandomInitvector();
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return base64_encode($iv) . ':' . base64_encode($ciphertext);
}

function aesCbcDecryptFromBase64($key, $data)
{
    list($iv, $encryptedData) = explode(':', $data, 2);
    return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encryptedData), 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, base64_decode($iv));
}

echo 'AES CBC 256 String encryption with random key full' . PHP_EOL;

$plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
echo 'plaintext: ' . $plaintext . PHP_EOL;

// generate random key
$encryptionKey = generateRandomAesKey();
$encryptionKeyBase64 = base64Encoding($encryptionKey);
echo 'encryptionKey (Base64): ' . $encryptionKeyBase64 . PHP_EOL;

// encryption
echo PHP_EOL . '* * * Encryption * * *' . PHP_EOL;
$ciphertextBase64 = aesCbcEncryptToBase64($encryptionKey, $plaintext);
echo 'ciphertext: ' . $ciphertextBase64 . PHP_EOL;
echo 'output is (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext' .PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Cross platform cryptography: AES CBC 256 String encryption with random key (PHP)' . PHP_EOL;
// decryption
echo PHP_EOL . '* * * Decryption * * *' . PHP_EOL;
$decryptionKeyBase64 = $encryptionKeyBase64;
$ciphertextDecryptionBase64 = $ciphertextBase64;
echo 'decryptionKey (Base64): ' . $decryptionKeyBase64 . PHP_EOL;

echo 'ciphertextDecryption (Base64): ' . $ciphertextDecryptionBase64 . PHP_EOL;
echo 'input is (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext' .PHP_EOL;
$decryptionKey = base64Decoding($decryptionKeyBase64);
$decryptedtext = aesCbcDecryptFromBase64($decryptionKey, $ciphertextDecryptionBase64);
echo 'plaintext: ' . $decryptedtext . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

The output looks like:

```
AES CBC 256 String encryption with random key full
plaintext:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
encryptionKey (Base64): DuLNOxN3BUc+htgigTcQOeJsPuMkF/aBcyVSaXhMcEw=

* * * Encryption * * *
ciphertext: XvXGCOyMrj2ohknIr8k1+A==:nPrEGko/7OFRjiRCgX0Hryz0a+Qc6A9RmRlipWl+R6vslqLBf/8EZtGsf+zwwGAV
output is (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext

* * * Decryption * * *
decryptionKey (Base64): DuLNOxN3BUc+htgigTcQOeJsPuMkF/aBcyVSaXhMcEw=
ciphertext (Base64): XvXGCOyMrj2ohknIr8k1+A==:nPrEGko/7OFRjiRCgX0Hryz0a+Qc6A9RmRlipWl+R6vslqLBf/8EZtGsf+zwwGAV
input is (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext
plaintext:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```